# Why content-width:320 is ignored by Android and defaults to device-width? How to fix to 320?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-browser

according to http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

"Width values that are (...) less than (or equal to) 320 result in a value equal to the device-width"

Does anyone know how to force the viewport to be exactly 320px wide for all Android devices ?

Many thanks!